# Need help with drupal, ubercart and a module hook on product load

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I am trying to make a module that works with ubercart.  What I need to know is how do I hook into the loading of a product.  I want to modify some of the data slightly before any output.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use hook_nodeapi and the load view $op to add/alter data.

http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi

This function is fired when a node is being loaded. What you will want to do is:

```
mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
   switch ($op) {
      case 'load':
        if ($node->type == 'product') {
            var_dump($node);
        }
   }
}
```

Try that out. That should dump the node object if the node is a product, and you can see how to add/alter data in the node object from there.

Comment: Thanks that was a lot easier than I thought it was going to be.